# Koin custom lifetime of service

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

I am trying to setup/extend Koin so that it respects the lifetime of a Ktor request.
I would like to inject a new service instance per request and share it throughout, but destroy it at request end.

Has anyone already tried this? Is it possible to extend Koin to handle this scenario or should I just build something on my own?

Ideally I'm looking to create something like this:

```
single<CoolService> { CoolServiceImpl() }
factory<CoolerService> { CoolerServiceImpl() }
request<CoolestService> { CoolestServiceImpl() } // THIS
```

Comment: Is this feature request https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1374 related to your problem?

Comment: That is my problem :)
I am willing to contribute to Koin myself, but I am looking for how to connect to Ktor context

Comment: This is something that I think should just be handled in the ktor request pipeline? Put your factory into a koin module, grab it in the pipeline, put a new instance in the request context, grab it from there when you handle the request?

Comment: Here are a few examples of different context interception tools https://github.com/lgwillmore/warden/blob/main/ktor/src/main/kotlin/code/laurence/warden/ktor/PipelineBlocks.kt